# Android: How to use android lint's args " --sources" and "----resources"?

Tags: java, android, lint

I enter the project root path and just set

lint --check UnusedResources --quiet --fullpath --sources ./src --resources ./res ./

but it can not work.

Comment: I think you missing your project name at last : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html

Comment: my project path is "./"